# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Tags: android, android-volley, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

Using volley for basic network operations,getting no connection handshake error when adding the project as an module.

While the module works fine in some another project.

On R&D, added retrypolicy but no use still getting the same error.

Here is my code.
https://gist.github.com/fizzysoftware/a895bc2cbd1ad9a048277859f3f23963

Answer (score 4):

It could be one of these two cases:

1. You try to connect to an HTTP url but it's actually an HTTPS url, or
2. You try to connect to an HTTPS page but the certificate is not valid.

These are at least the cases I've encountered so far...

Comment: no actually the url is https only and it is working fine in marshmallow version but not in kitkat.

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see how you try to call it. And logcat please :)

Comment: Sure see my edited question. Volley server error i am getting with message com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Comment: I got the response when changing https to http

Comment: Thanks. I used https in a http url. Now problem solved

Answer (score 3):

Changing the url from Https to Http will work.

Comment: remove the http: // www.   part from URL.

Answer (score 0):

In my project also same issues are faced. In Marshmallow its work suffecfully. But in Kitkat version it raised the issue

"com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed"

For Handling this I used google's auth dependencies. Kindly add the following dependency in your Gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
```

And Implement the method for Installing Security Provider in Lower versions, If instalation's required

```
private void updateAndroidSecurityProvider(Activity callingActivity) {
try {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    // Thrown when Google Play Services is not installed, up-to-date, or enabled
    // Show dialog to allow users to install, update, or otherwise enable Google Play services.
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), callingActivity, 0);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    Log.e("SecurityException", "Google Play Services not available.");
}
```

}

Then call the method in your activity, before making network operations.